# Numpy "Fortran"-like reshape?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have an array `X` of shape `(6, 2)` like this:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
```

I want to reshape it to an array of shape `(3, 2, 2)`, so I did this:

```
X.reshape(3, 2, 2)
```

And got:

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
```

However, I need my data in a different format. To be precise, I want to end up wth:

```
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 9,  10]],

       [[ 5, 6],
        [11, 12]]])
```

Should I be using `reshape` for this or something else? What's the best way to do this in Numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify order;

```
X.reshape(3, 2, 2, order='F')
```

should work

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the order option:

```
>>> X.reshape(3, 2, 2, order='F')
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [11, 12]]])
```

> ‘F’ means to read / write the elements using Fortran-like index order, with the first index changing fastest, and the last index changing slowest.

see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 4):

A functional  equivalent to the `order='F'` reshape:

```
In [31]: x.reshape(2,3,2).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[31]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [11, 12]]])

In [32]: x.reshape(2,3,2).transpose(1,0,2).strides
Out[32]: (16, 48, 8)
```

Without the transpose the strides would be (48,16,8).

A thing that's a bit tricky about this layout is that the last dimension remains in 'C' order.  It's the just first two dimension that are switched.

The full 'F' layout would be

```
In [33]: x = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,2,2,order='F')
In [34]: x
Out[34]: 
array([[[ 1,  7],
        [ 4, 10]],

       [[ 2,  8],
        [ 5, 11]],

       [[ 3,  9],
        [ 6, 12]]])
```

Comment: None of these operations requires data to be copied, which is nice. The first adjusts shape, the second strides.